# Can't get height of Widgets

Tags: android

I am facing a problem when gets height/width of TextView.

My code :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    int h1 = tv1.getHeight();
    TextView tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview2);
    int h2 = tv2.getHeight();
}
```

h1 is height of textview1
h2 is height of textview2

These h1 and h2 are always equal to 0.

What is wrong here ?

Please advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`View.getWidth()/View.getHeight()` won't give you a meaningful answer until the view has been measured.
Read about [how android draws views](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html) here.
See this [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/9cd129eb10673e2c/ba8170c29dd5c76c?lnk=gst&q=getHeight%28%29#ba8170c29dd5c76c) to get an idea of when the measured dimensions will be available.

Answer (score 0):

tv1.getHeight() will return 0 (as well as tv2.getWidth()) if it's not drawed yet.

Solution would be to get the height after your view is layouted:

```
tv1.post(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
         int height = tv1.getHeight();
    }
});
tv2.post(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
         int height = tv2.getHeight();
    }
});
```