# get height of a linearlayout

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

I'd like to get the height of a `linearlayout`. I found more information in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956838/cant-get-height-of-widgets)

> `View.getWidth()/View.getHeight()` won't  give you a meaningful answer until the view has been measured.

How will I know that view has been measured? Is there some event for it?

**UPD:**

Solution for me is to get layout's height in overriden onWindowFocusChanged()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently aren't any events that will fire that specifically tell you the size of a view has changed.  As suggested in the threads you pointed to, you can check for when the view has focus, and assume that once it has focus, it has width/height greater than 0.

Another way:  There's an [onSizeChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method which you can override in a subclass and use to do something when non-zero values come in.  Obviously, be sure to call super.onSizeChanged(...).

Comment: "assume that once it has focus, it has width/height greater than 0" .. may be it's not so intelligent answer, but should I do it within a while loop?! ... i try tomorrow your second suggestion ... android thing are too complicated

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) it was enough for me to get height in onWindowFocusChanged() :)